# How to get rid of this System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0 error in my test class

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

I am trying to create a new case with record type to cover the lines in my apex class but throwing the inbound error. please help me to cover the lines
[image]
 **This is the full  method**

```
public void onAfterInsert()
    {
        // don't do anything if not licensed
        if (!FMA_isEnabled)
        {
            return;
        }

        // reset class variables
        carePlanList = new List<Case>();
        carePlanIds  = new List<Id>();
        dmlOpts      = new Database.DMLOptions();

        // map referral Case to careplan Case
        Map<Id,Id> refToPlanMap = new Map<Id, Id>();

        for (Case caseObj : newLst)
        {
            // if record type is CarePlan
            if (
                rtIdMap.containsKey(caseObj.RecordTypeId)
                &&
                rtIdMap.get(caseObj.RecordTypeId).getDeveloperName() == 'CarePlan'
                &&
                Util.getRecordTypeNamespace(caseObj.RecordTypeId) == 'HealthCloudGA'
                &&
                caseObj.Associated_Referral__c != null
            )
            {
                handleNewCarePlanAssignment(caseObj);

                refToPlanMap.put(caseObj.Associated_Referral__c, caseObj.Id);
            }
        }

        // set in handleNewCarePlanAssignment
        if (!carePlanIds.isEmpty() &&
            Schema.sObjectType.Case.fields.Assign_using_active_assignment_rule__c.isUpdateable()
            &&
            Schema.sObjectType.Case.fields.ParentId.isUpdateable())
        {
            for (Case plan : [SELECT Id, Assign_using_active_assignment_rule__c FROM CASE WHERE Id IN :carePlanIds])
            {
                plan.Assign_using_active_assignment_rule__c = false;
                plan.ParentId = null;
                plan.setOptions(dmlOpts);
                carePlanList.add(plan);
            }
        }

        // update care plans
        if(!carePlanList.isEmpty()){
            update carePlanList;
        }

        if (!refToPlanMap.keySet().isEmpty() && Schema.sObjectType.Case.fields.ParentId.isUpdateable()
            &&
            Schema.sObjectType.Case.fields.ConvertedToCarePlan__c.isUpdateable())
        {
            // get referral cases to update
            for (Case refCase : [SELECT Id, ConvertedToCarePlan__c, ParentId FROM Case WHERE Id IN :refToPlanMap.keySet()])
            {
                // set parent Careplan Case
                refCase.ParentId = refToPlanMap.get(refCase.Id);
                refCase.ConvertedToCarePlan__c = true;

                // add to list of updates
                referralList.add(refCase);
            }
        }

        // update referrals
        if(!referralList.isEmpty()){
            update referralList;
        }
    }
```

**Test Class method**

@testSetup
    static void setup()
    {
        UserTest.initTestUsers();

```
    TestUtilities.IS_FMA_ENABLED = true;

    System.runAs(UserTest.getTestUser(UserTest.UserType.mcm))
    {
        // TODO :: change to SOQL & filter by namespace?
        Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> caseRTMap = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName();

        // Account
        Account testPatient = TestUtilities.createPatientAccount();

        // Program
        HealthCloudGA__Program__c testProgram = (HealthCloudGA__Program__c) COMM_DataFactory.createSObject(new HealthCloudGA__Program__c(
                Name = 'Unit Test Program',
                HealthCloudGA__StartDate__c = Date.today(),
                HealthCloudGA__EndDate__c = Date.today() + 1
        ), true);

        Case referralCase = (Case) COMM_DataFactory.createSObject(
            new Case
            (
                RecordTypeId = caseRTMap.get('Referral').getRecordTypeId(),
                Program_Name__c = testProgram.Id
            ),
            true
        );
```

Case carePlanCase = (Case) COMM_DataFactory.createSObject(
                new Case
                (
                    RecordTypeId = caseRTMap.get('carePlan').getRecordTypeId(),
                    Program_Name__c = testProgram.Id
                ),
                true
            );
        }
    }

```
 @isTest
    static void testOnAfterInsert()
    {
        TestUtilities.IS_FMA_ENABLED = true;

        System.runAs(UserTest.getTestUser(UserTest.UserType.mcm))
        {
            Test.startTest();

            Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> caseRTMap = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName();

            List<Case> referralCase = [
                    SELECT Id, Program_Name__c, ContactId
                    FROM Case
                    WHERE RecordTypeId = :caseRTMap.get('Referral').getRecordTypeId()
            ];

             List<Case> carePlanCase = [
                    SELECT Id, Program_Name__c, ContactId
                    FROM Case
                    WHERE RecordTypeId = :caseRTMap.get('CarePlan').getRecordTypeId()
            ];



            Case carePlan = new Case();
            carePlan.RecordTypeId = caseRTMap.get('CarePlan').getRecordTypeId();
            carePlan.Program_Name__c = referralCase[0].Program_Name__c;
            carePlan.Associated_Referral__c = referralCase[0].Id;
            insert carePlan;
           Case Referral = new Case();
            Referral.RecordTypeId = caseRTMap.get('CarePlan').getRecordTypeId();
           Referral.Program_Name__c = carePlanCase[0].Program_Name__c;
          Referral.Associated_Referral__c = carePlanCase[0].Id;
            system.debug('referral'+ carePlanCase);
            insert Referral;


if(!carePlanCase.isEmpty()){
 carePlan.ParentId = referralCase[0].ParentId;
}

            referralCase = [
                    SELECT Id, ConvertedToCarePlan__c
                    FROM Case
                    WHERE RecordTypeId = :caseRTMap.get('Referral').getRecordTypeId()
            ];

            System.assert(referralCase[0].ConvertedToCarePlan__c == true, 'Referral Case - Converted to Care Plan not updated.');

            Test.stopTest();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Worrying about code coverage is premature when your unit tests *are not working*, which is the case here. This line:

```
Referral.Program_Name__c = carePlanCase[0].Program_Name__c;
```

throws an exception on accessing element `0` because that element does not exist - the list is empty.

So the next thing you do is look where the list came from:

```
         List<Case> carePlanCase = [
                SELECT Id, Program_Name__c, ContactId
                FROM Case
                WHERE RecordTypeId = :caseRTMap.get('CarePlan').getRecordTypeId()
        ];
```

and then you ask "Why is this query not returning any records?"

Now that can come from a variety of reasons - problems with criteria and so on - but here it's because you haven't created any data that matches the query. Reminder: unit tests can *only* access the records that they themselves create. You must create data that will match each query you expect to have a non-empty result.

I highly recommend reading *all* of the questions about unit tests under [canonical-qa](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=canonical-qa) to learn how to write unit tests well. They are your chief guard against losing the trust of your users by shipping poor quality software.

Comment: I do not have problem with  ```carePlan.Program_Name__c = referralCase[0].Program_Name__c;``` I have a problem with  ``` Referral.Program_Name__c = carePlanCase[0].Program_Name__c;```  and I queried the Program_Name__c in my list

Comment: Is there an `@testSetup` method you have not shown us? Where is this data being created? The answer ultimately is the same - you have to make sure you have test data that matches your queries.

Comment: Yes @testSetup is there. I've added in my test class above. can you take a look on it.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the data created in testSetup, but ultimately it's exactly the same answer. You need to create the right data to match _all_ of your queries.

Comment: create the right data means do I need to create a case data again in setup ?

Comment: You need to create a Case that matches what your unit test uses, yes.

Comment: I am getting this error after creating test data.
```ttempt to de-reference a null object``` and please look at my setup I just created before closing the method

Comment: You will need to work through each error as it comes. Read the text carefully; it's telling you _exactly_ what the problem is. Learning how to handle this type of error is fundamental to being a developer, and you will find may resources if you search SFSE.